# How fill formik initialValue?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to create an "update form",so I'm trying to complete my initials values.
I don't understand why but my form continue to display empty fields even though I receive my data.

I got from my database my Indicator  (indicatorSelected), I can display it in my console.

```js
Object {
    "display_order": 1,
    "graphic_type": "Camembert",
    "hidden": 1,
    "id_indicator": 4,
    "id_user": undefined,
    "title": "2",
    "type": "Text",
  }
```

Could you help me ?

```js
const [indicatorSelected, setIndicatorSelected] = useState(null);
const [initialValue, setInitialValue] = useState({
   title: "",
   hidden: false,
   order: "",
   graphicType: ""
});

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!indicatorSelected) return;
        setInitialValue({
            title: indicatorSelected.title,
            hidden: indicatorSelected.hidden,
            order: indicatorSelected.display_order,
            graphicType: indicatorSelected.graphic_type
        })
    }, [indicatorSelected]);

return(  ...
        <Formik
                initialValues={initialValue} ..> ...);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `enableReinitialize`, see: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/811

Answer (score 1):

Have you set  enableReinitialize?

**By default, Formik doesnot reinitialize values once initialized.**

```
return(  ...
        <Formik
                enableReinitialize={true}
                initialValues={initialValue} ..> ...);
```